# Ansible configure and compile in directory

Tags: ansible, configuration-management, vagrant, installation

So I have have an Ansible Task that extracts a programs sourcecode zip into a certain directory and is then supposed to compile and install it.
The extraction of the zip works fine, but then I need to execute the commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And these commands need to be execute from within the extracted directory. I tried several things to execute it, I couldnt get it to work.

```
  - name: doit
    command: chdir=/tmp/proftpd/ ./configure && make && make install
    become: yes
```

I tried this but it fails:

```
  TASK [doit] ********************************************************************
fatal: [centos]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["./configure", "&&", "make", "&&", "make", "install"], "delta": "0:00:00.152824", "end": "2019-11-21 14:20:48.656070", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-11-21 14:20:48.503246", "stderr": "configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target\nconfigure: WARNING: invalid host type: &&\nconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target\nconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target\nconfigure: WARNING: invalid host type: &&\nconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target\nconfigure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target\nInvalid configuration `&&': machine `&&' not recognized\nconfigure: error: /bin/sh .//config.sub && failed", "stderr_lines": ["configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target", "configure: WARNING: invalid host type: &&", "configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target", "configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target", "configure: WARNING: invalid host type: &&", "configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target", "configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target", "Invalid configuration `&&': machine `&&' not recognized", "configure: error: /bin/sh .//config.sub && failed"], "stdout": "checking build system type... ", "stdout_lines": ["checking build system type... "]}
```

How can I achieve this properly with ansible?

Answer (score 4):

Ansible `command` module requires only one command and cannot be changed. You should use the `shell` module at the very least. Note however that this will break the idempotency of the playbook.

You should probably split the task up into three:

- configure task using the `shell` module. Use `creates:` to tell the task to be skipped if the configure task has already created the expected output file
- make task, using [the Ansible Make module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/make_module.html#make-module)
- similarly for the make install task.

This should yield the same actual result, but would be more likely to be idempotent.

Comment: How exactly would I specify the make and the make install tasks. I do know about the `make` keyword, but all my previous attempts didn't work correctly.

Comment: did you use the `target` parameter of the module? by setting the target parameter (ie target=install) you could run the make install.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.
Splitting it up into more commands worked perfectly

```
  - name: doit
    command: chdir=/tmp/proftpd/ ./configure

  - name: a shit here we go again
    command: chdir=/tmp/proftpd/ make

  - name: another one
    command: chdir=/tmp/proftpd/ sudo make install
```